# How to manually build predictions from xgboost model

Tags: r, xgboost

I am trying to figure out how to generate probabilities from the xgboost model tree so they match what I would get from the `predict` function.

First I build the model

```
library(xgboost)
#install.packages("ModelMetrics")
library(ModelMetrics)

set.seed(100)

# - Extreme gbm
y = as.integer(testDF$y)

x = testDF[,-which(names(testDF) %in% c('y'))]
var.names <- names(x)
x = as.matrix(x)
x = matrix(as.numeric(x),nrow(x),ncol(x))

nround = 10

XX <- xgboost(param=param, data = x, label = y, nrounds=nround, missing = NA)
```

Then I wrote some code to build all of the rules that would result in a particular leaf

```
baseTree <- xgb.model.dt.tree(model = XX)

Leafs <- filter(baseTree, Feature == 'Leaf')
Branches <- filter(baseTree, Feature != 'Leaf')

Branches$Feature = var.names[as.numeric(Branches$Feature) + 1]

FullRules = rep(NA, nrow(Leafs))


AllRules <- foreach(i = 1:nrow(Leafs), .combine = 'rbind') %do% {

  theLeaf = Leafs[i,]
  theNode = theLeaf$Node
  theID = theLeaf$ID

  count = 1

  RuleText = ''
  while(theNode != 0){

    FF <- filter(Branches, Yes == theID | No == theID | Missing == theID)
    isYes = FF$Yes == theID
    isNo = FF$No == theID
    isMissing = FF$Missing == theID

    FullRules[i] = ifelse(isYes & isMissing
      , paste0("(", FF$Feature, " < ", FF$Split, " | is.na(", FF$Feature, "))")
      , NA)
    FullRules[i] = ifelse(isNo & isMissing
      , paste0("(", FF$Feature, " >= ", FF$Split, " | is.na(", FF$Feature, "))")
      , FullRules[i])
    FullRules[i] = ifelse(isYes & !isMissing
      , paste0(FF$Feature, " < ", FF$Split)
      , FullRules[i])
    FullRules[i] = ifelse(isNo & !isMissing
      , paste0(FF$Feature, " >= ", FF$Split)
      , FullRules[i])
    FullRules[i] = ifelse(isMissing & !isYes & !isNo
      , paste0("is.na(", FF$Feature, ")")
      , FullRules[i])

    if(count == 1){
      RuleText = FullRules[i]
    } else{
      RuleText = paste0(RuleText, " & ", FullRules[i])
    }

    theNode = FF$Node
    theID = FF$ID
    count = count + 1
  }

  data.frame(
    Leafs[i,]
    ,RuleText
  )

}
```

Now I pick out 1 row and attempted to match the probabilities.  In this case it matches. The loop will go through and indicate TRUE for all of the rules that are met for this particular customer.  Then I can filter down to those rows and sum those up to get the logodds estimates.  Then I convert those to probabilities.

```
TT <- testDF[25,]

ff <- foreach(i = 1:nrow(AllRules), .combine = 'rbind') %do% {
  TT %>% transmute_(
    Tree = as.character(AllRules$RuleText[i])
    , Quality = AllRules$Quality[i])
}


predict(XX, as.matrix(TT[,var.names]))
#[1] 0.05571342

filter(ff, Tree) %>% 
  summarise(
    Q1 = sum(sqrt(Quality^2))
    # ,Q2 = sum(sqrt(Quality^2))
    , Prob1 = exp(Q1)/(1+exp(Q1))
    , Prob2 = 1-Prob1
    )
#        Q1     Prob1     Prob2
#1 2.830209 0.9442866 0.0557134
```

But in this case it does not match the predict function...

```
TT <- testDF[17,]

ff <- foreach(i = 1:nrow(AllRules), .combine = 'rbind') %do% {
  TT %>% transmute_(
    Tree = as.character(AllRules$RuleText[i])
    , Quality = AllRules$Quality[i])
}


predict(XX, as.matrix(TT[,var.names]))
#[1] 0.1386877

filter(ff, Tree) %>% 
  summarise(
    Q1 = sum(sqrt(Quality^2))
    # ,Q2 = sum(sqrt(Quality^2))
    , Prob1 = exp(Q1)/(1+exp(Q1))
    , Prob2 = 1-Prob1
    )
#        Q1    Prob1    Prob2
#1 1.967608 0.877354 0.122646
```

Answer (score 1):

To generate the prediction you just need to sum up the values of the individual leafs that the person falls within for each booster

```
filter(ff, Tree) %>% 
  summarise(
    Q1 = sum(Quality)
    , Prob1 = exp(Q1)/(1+exp(Q1))
    , Prob2 = 1-Prob1
    )
```